# chrome extension unfunctional double page load

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to webdev, but I'm trying to make a chrome extension that change currencies of prices. It requires taking all the content of a page

```
var content = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

Making changes to that, and then plugging it back in. This leads to ever page loading twice. It first loads, then it makes the changes (I can see all the css disappearing, then reappearing), and loads again with the changes. Then the changes are implemented using

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML = content
```

This is what I have right now in manifest.json

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["swap.js"]
    }
  ]
```

Another problem is that some pages stop being functional. I don't know how to showcase this, but pages like RegExr.com I can't change the text in it anymore (I just noticed that this is not persistent, which is confusing, but it happened in another couple of pages as well.)

So, yea.. anyone has any ideas about these two problems:

1. Stopping the double load.
2. Not making the page dysfunctional.

Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, changing innerHTML of the entire page is hardly useful for the exact reasons you've described. Find the element you want to change using document.querySelector and friends, or iterate over all elements using document.createTreeWalker, then change the element. There are tons of examples you can find by searching for "javascript modify page elements tutorial" and similar queries in google/whatever.

Comment: If you are only wanting to change *text* that is displayed, you should **not** be using `.innerHTML`. You should only be changing text nodes. While we could point to some examples, your question is too general for us to give really good advice as to what to do. Here are is a [search for questions/answers which should have some relevant information](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bgoogle-chrome-extension%5d%20NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT). Generally, you should avoid using `.innerHTML` unless you *know* that is what you *really* need. There can be many unintended consequences.